# Scraping class by value returns `{xml_nodeset (0)}`

Tags: rvest, rselenium

I'm trying to scrape a website `https://everesting.cc/hall-of-fame/#/` to get names of riders.
I used a [selector gadget](https://selectorgadget.com/) to find a class value. It's supposed to be `Rider__name`. However, when I use the code below, it returns nothing. What am I doing wrong?

```
library(rvest)
everesting_html<- read_html("https://everesting.cc/hall-of-fame/#/")
html_nodes(everesting_html, ".Rider__name")
```

Comment: rvest only scrapes the page source code, not the code generated by JS. You have to use RSelenium to scrape this website.

Comment: Thank you! Would you be able to answer it or at least offer some source?

Comment: This link might help: https://callumgwtaylor.github.io/blog/2018/02/01/using-rselenium-and-docker-to-webscrape-in-r-using-the-who-snake-database/

Comment: I don't think it's too hard but I'm quite lazy to use RSelenium.